# Getting "data _source is not implemented error" for Monte Carlo Simulation script

Tags: python

I'm basically trying to create a Monte Carlo simulation and I'm having an error when trying to fetch data.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 3)
end = dt.datetime(2018, 3, 3)

prices = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'Googl', start, end)['close']
returns  = prices.pct_change()

last_price = prices[-1]

#creating number of simulations
num_simulations = 1000
num_days = 252


simulation_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(num_simulations):
    count = 0 
    daily_vol = returns.std()

    price_series = []

    price = last_price * (1 +np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
    price_series.append(price)

    for y in range(num_days):
        if count == 251: 
            break 
        price  = price_series[count] * (1 +np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
        price_series.append(price)
        count += 1 

    simulation_df[x] = price_series
```

Here's the error line in my console:

```
data_source='Googl' is not implemented
```

I'm using this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_T0l015ecK4). I'm getting an error saying the data source is not implemented.

I'm trying to get Apple and Google's stock price from 1/3-3/1/2018 and run 1000 simulations on it. I'm wondering if it thinks Google should be something it should be retrieving data from instead of looking at its stock price.

It's not storing any values for Google or Apple's stock price and it's annoying me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced the following link and it has the same general scenario as what you describe. Try using ‘google’ instead of ‘googl’. The video also shows ‘google’

```
http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html

import pandas_datareader.data as web

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

f = web.DataReader('F', 'google', start, end)
```

Comment: I tried what you said. I adjusted the date and time even to your format, but it still doesn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled the pandas_datareader and it's still giving me that error.

From what I've read, pandas has trouble getting historical data from Google Finance and Yahoo finance too.